# Storing a multidimensional array in a cookie?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

Today I have a Ajax solution where the server keeps track of selections are doing and updates the page. I'm redoing this so it will be all done with javascript on the client until the user actually submit the data, performance where quite bad under load with the old solution. (C#, ASP.NET 4.0)

Found a nice way of storing an Array by first serialize it with json [link text](http://www.phpied.com/json-javascript-cookies/)

Say I have an array like this: {Id, Value}

Any advise how I can store several of the arrays above to a cookie?

Comment: Just keep in mind you can only store up to 4KB per cookies. Also keep in mind that the larger your cookies, the more data the client has to send when performing requests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Say I have an array like this: {Id, Value}

That's not an array. That's an object. You can multiple copies of those in an array:

```
[
    {"foo": "bar"},
    {"foo": "baz"},
    {"foo": "boom"}
]
```

That's a valid [JSON](http://json.org) string for an array containing objects —in this case, objects with a single property, `foo`, each of which has its own value, but the objects don't have to have the same properties, and they can have multiple properties. For instance:

```
[
    {},
    ["zero", "one", "two", "three"],
    "I'm just a string",
    {
       "f0": "foo zero",
       "f1": "foo one",
       "f2": "foo two",
       "all": ["foo zero", "foo one", "foo two"]
    },
    42
]
```

That's a valid JSON string for an array with five entries:

- An object with no properties (e.g., a "blank" object).
- An array with four entries.
- A string.
- An object with four properties: `f0`, `f1`, `f2`, and `all`. `f0`, `f1`, and `f2` all have string values; `all` has an array of strings as a value.
- [The answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_answer_to_life_the_universe_and_everything#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe_and_Everything_.2842.29) to Life, The Universe, and Everything.

You can turn an object or array into a valid JSON string (stringify), and reverse the process (parse) client-side using any of several libraries. Crockford (the inventer of JSON) has several on [his github page](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/), most notably json2.js although json2.js relies on `eval` for parsing; since that's not really ideal you can use `json_parse.js` (a recursive descent parser that doesn't use `eval`) or `json_parse_state.js` (a state machine that doesn't use `eval`) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.stringify` to generate a string from the array object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836459(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Cookies only store simple strings. You can come up with you own system something like this:

```
$content = [id,value];[text,textvalue];
setcookie("Array", $content);
```

When you want it back, you explode the string at delimiters (in this case ';' and ',')

Answer (score 1):

Converting an array into a string:

```
> JSON.stringify([1, 2])
*returns* '[1, 2]'
```

We can then make it a cookie:

```
> $.cookie('cookie', '[1, 2]')
```

And then parse it:

```
> JSON.parse($.cookie('cookie'))
*returns* [1, 2]
```